# Can I find and replace a string in an entire postgresql database of a Django project?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm looking to find and replace every instance of a certain string within a database that drives a Django project. Is there a way that I can write a management command that searches every table of the database for a string, and then replace any instances of it that it finds? I don't particularly care about the speed of the operation.

The use case is unusual, but a product has been rebranded and I don't want to have to manually rename every instance of the old product.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: But how would you determine in which field to look for string if there are multiple models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel like brute-forcing:

```
from django.db import connection
tables = connection.introspection.table_names()

for model in connection.introspection.installed_models(tables):
    print model.__name__
    print model._meta.db_table
    print model._meta.get_all_field_names()
```